# How to find graph schema in Gremlin?

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I wanna to find all node and edge properties in graph. How can I list node (or edge) properties that exist in graph?

for example if nodes has 3 non-reserved properties such as NAME, education, gender. I wanna a methods like

```
g.V().schema().toList();
// result: [ID, LABEL, NAME, GENDER, EDUCATION]
```

Comment: I search my question with many keywords in google and stackoverflow and try to find a method in gremlin by IDE autocomplete. what effort can I do more? I should emphasis that I try much to find my answer?

Comment: There might be no such thing as a "schema" - each node might have different properties and edges. Otherwise just modify my answer below to printout the keys instead of the values - you also only jave to visit one node (per nodeType) to get the information if your graph is uniform in the sense that a schema makes sense. What kind of "schema" are you interested in - please state your expectations more clearly.

Comment: I don't understand your question. I wanna to find out which information is in a specific node. i. e. exploratory data analysis.

Comment: I assume you are interested in the names and types of the properties as well as the names and "types" of the edges. I modified my answer accordingly. I tried to understand your hint with "exploratory data analysis" looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploratory_data_analysis and it seems only remotely related to the graph issue. So please explain what your needs are in more detail best with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all nodes have a same properties. we can find the properties of the first vertex and generalize it to all nodes:

```
TinkerGraph tg = TinkerGraph.open() ;
tg.io(IoCore.graphml()).readGraph("src\\main\\resources\\air-routes.graphml");
GraphTraversalSource g = tg.traversal();

g.V().propertyMap().select(Column.keys).next();
// result = {LinkedHashSet@1831}  size = 12
// 0 = "country"
// 1 = "code"
// 2 = "longest"
// 3 = "city"
// 4 = "elev"
// 5 = "icao"
// 6 = "lon"
// 7 = "type"
// 8 = "region"
// 9 = "runways"
// 10 = "lat"
// 11 = "desc"
```

but If there is no guaranty to each node has a same set of properties, I don't find any other solution instead of retrieving all properties in a Map List and find distinct property with java collection methods (outside Gremlin).

Answer (score 7):

Gremlin itself has no notion of schema. This was a deliberate design choice as the capabilities and behavior around schema APIs is quite different from one graph system implementation to the next and forming an appropriate abstraction in Apache TinkerPop for that is quite difficult. In this way it is quite akin to TinkerPop 2.x's attempt to build a general index API, which ended up being too generic to be useful to anyone and had there been more complexity added, more that what was required for most cases. In the end, like indexing APIs, ideas for generalizing schema were left out for TinkerPop 3.x.

If you use a graph that allows for schema definition like JanusGraph or DSE Graph you should simply use the underlying Schema API of that graph system to get all of your schema values. If you aren't using that type of graph then you will need to do something along the lines of what has been offered in the other answers thus far and iterate through all of the vertices (or edges) and get the unique property keys. Here's my version:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().properties().key().dedup()
==>name
==>age
==>lang
```

The problem here is that to do this type of traversal, you will require a full graph scan, which will be problematic if you have a large graph. In those cases you will need to use an OLAP-based traversal with Spark or the like.

Comment: For example refer to https://docs.janusgraph.org/basics/schema/ for JanusGraph's Schema API.

Answer (score 0):

The last two lines in the JUnit Test Case might be closer to do what you want.
see also:

https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.simplegraph/blob/master/simplegraph-core/src/test/java/com/bitplan/simplegraph/core/TestTinkerPop3.java

```
graph.traversal().V().next().properties()
    .forEachRemaining(prop -> System.out.println(String.format("%s=%s",
        prop.label(), prop.value().getClass().getSimpleName())));
graph.traversal().V().next().edges(Direction.OUT)
    .forEachRemaining(edge -> System.out.println(
        String.format("%s->%s", edge.label(), edge.outVertex().label())));
```

producing:

```
name=String
age=Integer
created->person
knows->person
```

**JUnit Test Case**

```
  @Test
  public void testSchema() {
    Graph graph = TinkerFactory.createModern();
    graph.traversal().V().next().properties()
        .forEachRemaining(prop -> System.out.println(String.format("%s=%s",
            prop.label(), prop.value().getClass().getSimpleName())));
    graph.traversal().V().next().edges(Direction.OUT)
        .forEachRemaining(edge -> System.out.println(
            String.format("%s->%s", edge.label(), edge.outVertex().label())));
  }
```

Comment: I want nodes schema not values. You know that your nodes has a 'name' property, but I'm not. It seems that gremlin does not a method to get the schema directly. Am I true?

Comment: I changed my answer. It has duplicate edge information at this time but should be close to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.get("/schema")
async def schema():
    """Get Schema manually."""

    # Fetch edges_raw_dict using gremlin
    edges_raw_dict = tinker.g.E().group().by(T.label).by(
        __.project('in', 'out', 'properties')
        .by(__.inV().label())
        .by(__.outV().label())
        .by(__.properties().group().by(T.key).by(__.value().fold()))
        .dedup().fold()
    ).next()

    separator = "|"
    edges = []

    for edge_label, edge_list in edges_raw_dict.items():
        edge_filtered = edge_list[0] if edge_list else None
        properties_filtered = edge_filtered.get('properties', {}) if edge_filtered else None

        for edge in edge_list[1:]:
            edge_properties = edge.get('properties', {})
            if edge_properties:
                for prop in edge_properties:
                    properties_filtered[prop].extend(edge_properties[prop])

        if not properties_filtered:
            edge_filtered.pop("properties")

        for prop in properties_filtered:
            properties_filtered[prop] = separator.join(properties_filtered[prop])

        edges.append({edge_label: edge_filtered})

    # Fetch vertices using gremlin
    vertices = tinker.g.V().group().by(T.label).by(__.properties().label().dedup().fold()).to_list()

return {"edges": edges, "vertices": vertices}
```

With the little help of python i got schema like this:

```
{
    "edges": [
        {
            "familiar with": {
                "in": "Sector",
                "out": "Character"
            }
        },
        {
            "actions": {
                "in": "Action",
                "out": "Character"
            }
        },
        {
            "current_goal": {
                "in": "Goal",
                "out": "Character"
            }
        },
        {
            "relation": {
                "in": "Character",
                "out": "Character",
                "properties": {
                    "type": "friend|son"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "current_action": {
                "in": "Action",
                "out": "Character"
            }
        },
        {
            "goals": {
                "in": "Goal",
                "out": "Character"
            }
        }
    ],
    "vertices": [
        {
            "Goal": [
                "duration",
                "permanent",
                "description",
                "location",
                "time",
                "repetition"
            ],
            "Action": [
                "duration",
                "description",
                "location",
                "time"
            ],
            "Character": [
                "evacuation",
                "rest",
                "traits",
                "occupation",
                "somnolence",
                "health",
                "last_name",
                "priority",
                "nutrition",
                "hydration",
                "innate_tendency",
                "location",
                "first_name",
                "age"
            ],
            "Sector": [
                "name"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```